# Why is func undefined in this context?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I have a function like

```
func()
{
    const curVal = this.curVal;
    const callAgain = () => { func(); };
    Axios.get('somecontroller/someaction')
        .then(response =>
        {
            const newVal = response.data.curVal;
            if(curVal === newVal)
                setTimeout(callAgain, 500);
            else
                // ....
        })
        .catch(response =>
        {
            // ...
        });
}
```

and my browser is complaining about the line

```
const callAgain = () => { func(); };
```

saying that `func` is `undefined`. Any idea why? How can I fix?

Comment: What is `func()\n{...}` exactly? Is it a function call followed by a block? If `func() { ... }` is an object method definition, then `func` is `undefined` because object methods  do not create a binding for themselves in local scope.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot define a function the way you posted.

However, you can for example use the `function` keyword to define your function:

```
function func() {
    ...
}

func(); // it works!
```

**Edit:**
According to your comment, this is a object method declaration. In order to make this work, you first need to make sure your browser supports this particular ES2015 feature or if not, you transpile it to valid ES5.

Then you should be able to access the function using `this.func()`:

```
 const callAgain = () => { this.func(); };
```

In case you are using `func()` e.g. as a callback for a DOM event, you also have to make sure that `this` is bound correctly in `func`, for example by explicitly binding it in the constructor:

```
constructor() {
    ...

    this.func = this.func.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: These are functions in a React class, like you see here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html

Comment: If that was the issue, wouldn't there be a different error?

Comment: @Ms.Corlib: so this is a class method definition? If yes, use `this.func()`.

Answer (score 1):

Define the function using either of the following:

```
function func(){ ... }
```

Or...

```
var func = function(){ ... }
```

---

When you define it like this:

```
func() { ... }
```

JavaScript thinks you're trying to execute an existing function called `func`, and then run the block of code `{ ... }`